# Focus issue on a listview with fastscrollbar enabled

Tags: android, android-listview, fastscroll

I'm having an issue with a listview.
It's displaying items with a checkbox on the right.
When I enables the fastscrolling, everytime I press on the checkbox, the fastscrollbar appears and it scrolls to the position I pressed rather than just checking the checkbox...

If it matters I enable the fastscrollbar dynamically depending on the number of items in the list.
How can I fix this focus issue ?

Edit: In fact I'm also having the same issue without a checkbox. When I press on the right of the listview item, it doesn't open the item like it should but it scrolls to the position I pressed. Same behavior in a GridView...

Comment: are you using holder for your list or not ?

Comment: Yes I'm using a view holder

Comment: As explained in my Edit it has nothing to do with my code. A simple Listview or Gridview with fastscrollenabled has this behavior. How to disable this default behavior ?